# Can someone explain this batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

Recently I've been trying to create my own batch commands to make everyday things a lot easier for me.  I wanted to create a script that deletes everything within my Temp folder since it is always getting flooded with unnecessary files.  I found this code online and it works, but I'm confused on what it's actually meant to do.  I understand certain parts of it, but the majority has me confused.  I understand it is using a `for`loop but that doesn't really tell me much.  I know logically it makes sense, but I feel like the documentation isn't clear for what the entire script is doing.  Anyway, here's the script:

```
set folder="C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the first two lines are very simple. It just sets a variable to a folder path, then `CD`s into the folder. [The `/d` flag](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) is for changing the drive (`C:`) if it's currently set to another one.

Now, the last one is [a for cycle](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html). What it does is, basically: for each file in [`dir /b`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), which shows all files in current directory in bare format (only names), it either executes  `rmdir`, which deletes a directory, or, if `rmdir` failed because the argument is not a directory, it just `del`s it. The `/s/q` stuff in both cases means: `/s` - delete from all subfolders, `/q` - do not prompt a `Y/N`.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Great! Do you know what the /F "delims=" %%i part means?

Comment: @KevTLW as the docs state, it sets the delimiter to an empty string, which sets it to default, which is a tab or space

Comment: @feakuru: you last comment is not quite correct: `"delims="` does set to "no delimiters", not to "default". the default delimiters TAB and SPACE are default, if there is *no* "delims" at all.

Comment: @Stephan sure, that's what I meant. Thanks for clearing it up :)

Answer (score 0):

The first line sets the value of the variable `folder`.

The second changes the drive and directory to the value assigned to `folder`.

The third first performs a directory list in basic form (names only) of the current directory (as has just been changed) and assigns each line of the resultant list, in its entirety, to `%%i` in turn.

The name `%%i` is then removed using a `rmdir` or `rd` command in `/q` quiet mode and `/s` including any subdirectories. This works on directories, but not files. The `||` invokes a `del` command, again with `/s /q`with the same meanings and `del` deletes files.

hence, any name that is a directory is deleted, and if it's a file, then the `rmdir` fails and so the `del` deletes it.

The quotes are to ensure that any name encountered that contains a separator like space or comma is interpreted correctly.